# osx - write and exec on allocated memory page

Tags: c, macos, memory

I am stuck with a problem regarding memory mapping on OS X.

I am using the `mmap` call to map a memory region near a specific function. The idea is to later `jmp` to this allocated memory region using a relative jump. Code:

```
void *alloc;
if((alloc = mmap((void*)func, 12, PROT_EXEC|PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON, -1, 0)) == MAP_FAILED)
        printf("failed\n");
```

No problems for now. Memory gets mapped near `func`, by avoiding the use of `MAP_FIXED` flag, the kernel places it in a nearby location.

Then I simply craft a shellcode with the `E9` opcode (`jmp`) + the relative offset, calculated by subtracting the function (`func`) address and the allocated area (`alloc`) address.

```
char jmp32[] = {
     '\xE9', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00'
};

int *offset = malloc(4);
*offset = (int)(alloc-func);

memcpy(jmp32+1, offset, 4);
```

The shellcode is crafted fine, and its ready to be placed in memory.

```
vm_protect(mach_task_self(), (vm_address_t)func, 16, 0, VM_PROT_ALL); //make function area writable

memcpy(func, jmp32, sizeof(jmp32)); // place the jmp
```

Now, everything seems fine, but when I execute the program (and obviously call `func`):

```
(lldb) r
Process 3563 launched: './mempool' (x86_64) // don't mind the name, was using an old Xcode project
ffffffe9 //
60       //
43       // output there, as you can see, the shellcode is crafted fine!
03       //
00       //
Process 3563 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x15f3e, 0x0000000100035fff, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x100036000)
    frame #0: 0x0000000100035fff
```

So, investigating further:

```
(lldb) d -F intel -n test
mempool`test at main.c:97:
   0x100000ca0:  or     dword ptr [rax + 0x43], esp  //OR?!?
   0x100000ca3:  add    eax, dword ptr [rax]
   0x100000ca5:  sub    esp, 0x10
   0x100000ca8:  lea    rdi, qword ptr [rip + 0x2c3] ; "culo here: %p\n"
   0x100000caf:  lea    rax, qword ptr [rip - 0x16] ; test at main.c:97
   0x100000cb6:  mov    rsi, rax
   0x100000cb9:  mov    al, 0x0
   0x100000cbb:  call   0x100000ee4               ; symbol stub for: printf
   0x100000cc0:  mov    dword ptr [rbp - 0x4], eax
   0x100000cc3:  add    rsp, 0x10
   0x100000cc7:  pop    rbp
   0x100000cc8:  ret
```

The instruction is there, at the start of the function, but it's an `OR`. Not a `JMP`. Going deeper:

```
(lldb) mem read 0x100000ca0
0x100000ca0: 09 60 43 03 00 83 ec 10 48 8d 3d c3 02 00 00 48  .`C...?.H.=?...H
0x100000cb0: 8d 05 ea ff ff ff 48 89 c6 b0 00 e8 24 02 00 00  ..????H.ư.?$...
```

We can actually see that the `E9`, aka the `JMP` opcode got corrupted into a `09` opcode, which stands for the `OR` instruction.

I got various results, but the `E9` opcode always gets modified. I must assume this is the *W^X* memory protection mechanism I read about some time ago, right? Also, guess what, removing the `PROT_EXEC` flag in the `mmap` call leaves the opcode intact.

I really don't know if there is any way to go around this, but I assume there is, since [mach_override](https://github.com/rentzsch/mach_override) does exactly what I want, and from the little I have seen in the code, it uses memory allocation to jump around in memory. I will read the code further, and try to understand how to do it, but I would love to hear a good explanation from someone here! Specifically:

1. Is this the *W^X* feature?
2. Are there any workarounds?
3. If no, how does `mach_override` do?

Sorry for the long post, but I wanted to clear everything out. And thanks to anybody who can help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a few hours of code reading, I solved it. Answer was in `mach_override` code, as I expected. It uses this piece of code:

```
jumpRelativeInstruction |= 0xE900000000000000LL;
jumpRelativeInstruction |= ((uint64_t)offset & 0xffffffff) << 24;
jumpRelativeInstruction = OSSwapInt64(jumpRelativeInstruction);
```

to manually craft a `JMP` instruction, ready to be placed in memory, with the correct endianness and everything. It completely avoids memory writing functions, such as `memset` or `memcpy` which probably perform checks. Then, it finally writes it in memory using a pointer dereference:

```
*originalFunctionPtr = jumpRelativeInstruction;
```

This overflows into the next function opcodes, overwriting them.

So, by tweaking the code I was able to fit it into mine and finally `JMP` into the allocated area!

```
(lldb) r
Process 869 launched: './mempool' (x86_64)
alloc: 0x100035000
func: 0x100000bf0
hooked!
Process 869 exited with status = 0 (0x00000000)
```